# Reading list of names into an array

Tags: c++

I've just realized that I've never learned to read strings from file, so I did a little messing around to figure it out, but I'm having a problem with my compiler.

For my programming class I use visual c++ 2010 because it is required and it hasn't given me much problem so I haven't switched to any other.

Anyways heres my code and my problem.
It is basically supposed to read in full names from a file and store them in an array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 const int maxsize = 100;
 string friendArray[maxsize];

 ifstream friends;
 friends.open("myFriends.dat");

 int sub = 0;

 while (friendArray[sub] <= 100)
 {
   getline(friends, friendArray[sub]);
   sub++;
 }

}
```

in my while loop, I am recieving: error: no operator "<=" matches these operands.

I'm getting the same thing with any other operators I use also.
Any help?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the line `while (friendArray[sub] <= 100)`? `friendArray` is an array of strings, which you cannot compare to an int.

Comment: you should use homework tag, I guess. Anyway, you are comparing string and number which is not correct.

Comment: It's not homework I'm just trying to get ready for finals

Comment: Well, friendArray[sub] is a string, not an integer... :)  Maybe you should try working with the count itself if you're trying to do something 100 times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want this instead:

```
while (sub < 100)
```

Originally, you were comparing a string to an integer literal. You obviously can't do that.

Note that I also changed the `<=` to `<` otherwise, you'll be overrunning the array.

Comment: Thanks I'm also new to arrays :p